# Ideas for Designing database schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on designing database backend for a employee work hours scheduling application.

Here is what I am trying to do.
Every employee will submit a request for each day of the week, the number of hours he wants to work for particular day of the week. He has to do that for 3 shifts and can only work in 1 shift per day.

Like he can request

Wednesday -> Shift-1 ->2 Hours
Thursday -> Shift-2 ->3 Hours

He can modify those hours as much as he like till certain date, but cannot reduce the hours he has entered, only increment.
Now managers can pull this data and then enter the number of hours they have accepted for the particular employee.
He can then generate a report of hours accepted.

I have decided following schema for the tables.

```
Employee Table => CREATE TABLE Employee(id int(10) AUTO_INREMENT
PRIMARY KEY,Name varchar(10),Trade varchar(10),Password varchar(10));

Requests Table => CREATE TABLE REQUEST(eId int(10),FOREIGN KEY (eid)
REFERENCES Employee(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,,shiftId int(10),dateId  
int(10),day1    
DATE,day2 DATE,day3 DATE,day4 DATE,day5 DATE,day6 DATE,day7 DATE);

Accepted table => CREATE TABLE REQUEST(eId
int(10),FOREIGN KEY (eid),shiftId int(10),
REFERENCES Employee(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,dateId int(10),day1    
DATE,day2 DATE,day3 DATE,day4 DATE,day5 DATE,day6 DATE,day7 DATE);
```

I am new to SQL and databases. Can someone suggest improvements with this schema or tell what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please reformulate your table definitions as `CREATE TABLE` statements so that they are unambiguous. I don't know what "day 1...day 7" means.

Comment: Is there some code missing? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Strawberry I have detailed schema? Can you let me know what did you not understand?